# Third Largest element in array

Tags: c

There are 6 test cases out of which 5 are correct.
The program is about to find the third largest element
       in an array. Could u find the error for which the last 
       test case can get pass?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void thirdLargest(int arr[],int arr_size);
int main()
{
    int n,a[1000],i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    thirdLargest(a,n);
    return 0;
}
void thirdLargest(int arr[],int arr_size)
{
    int i,j,temp;
    for(i=0;i<arr_size-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<arr_size-i-1;j++)
        {
            if(arr[j]>arr[j+1])
            {
                temp=arr[j];
                arr[j]=arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The third Largest element is %d",arr[arr_size-3]);
}
```

Comment: You do not describe the test case, so I assume it is an online judge with secret tests. Please do not expect us to win challenges for you.

Comment: But I can't resist, I think the error is in line 5, which probably contradicts the description of the challenge, I'd need to see it to verify. If you can fix the problem with this hint, then you still deserve to win the challenge.

Comment: You don't need to sort it, just iterate through the array and keep updated the 3 largest elements.

Comment: `scanf()` has a return value for a reason. Ignore it at your own risk.

Comment: What happens when there are more than 1000 elements?

Comment: @Quimby Sigh....

Comment: "The compiler sometimes doesn't work properly." If your college lab provides a faulty compiler then complain. Or consider that the mistake might be in the programs instead of the compiler...

Comment: I did help, according to the compromise described here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions (in a comment instead of an answer though). And by now at least two people implicity demonstrated that they find my hint to the point... If you do your part of the compromise I will upgrade to an answer and continue with more hints.

Comment: Read the lab description thoroughly. If you quote it here I will even also hint where the other half of the problem is.

Comment: @Yunnosch whatever...

Comment: Everything is fine...

Comment: Should I change int to unsigned long long??

Comment: Idk if it's what causes error, but in `thirdLargest` when `i` is 0 and`j` is `arr_size-1` you compare and swap an element out of array bounds. I don't remember if arrays of fixed length are initialized, but if not, you get an undefined behavior and maybe thats why compiler doesn't work properly sometimes?

Comment: @IcedLance `j` will never be `arr_size - 1`. The condition is in that case would be `j < arr_size - 1`

Comment: Oh right my bad.

Comment: ANIKET ROY By now you are probably wondering how to fix the negative score, i.e. the number of downvotes (none of which is by me by the way). A good chance would probably be to spend some work according to the compromise link I provided earlier. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @ANIKET ROY Maybe the problem is that if the array has duplicated values you should select the unique third largest element.

Comment: What's the incorrect test case? I think that for best performance you may use qsort instead to use your sort technique. However I think that is not a good idea to sort the array, you may compute only the 3 max values.

Answer (score 0):

For fun I've written a code that seems to solve your problem and also 4th, 5th level and so on; in addition I've added the capability to compute random numbers and/or manage level values at runtime.

You may obtain cases other than yours manipolating 2 preprocessor macros:

- `#define RAND_VALUE 0` 0 requires the numers are manually inserted, 1 computes random numbers.
- `#define LEVEL 3` 3 is to manage your case, other values other than 0 may manage other fixed cases (4th, 5th, ..., nth levels), 0 to manage dynamic allocation and the function receives the parameter `level`.

This code doesn't verifies if the inserted numbers are less than the value level. This might be a problem and should be corrected in some way.

Another case of fault might be the insertion of more than 1000 numbers. Also this case should be corrected in some way.

Here the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define LEVEL 3
#define RAND_VALUE 0

#ifndef LEVEL
int levelLargest(int * a, int len, unsigned int level);
#else
int levelLargest(int * a, int len);
#endif

#ifndef LEVEL
int levelLargest(int * a, int len, unsigned int level)
#else
int levelLargest(int * a, int len)
#endif
{
#if LEVEL == 0
    int i,j,k,* max;
    int l=(int)level;
    max=malloc(level*sizeof(int));
#else
    int i,j,k,max[LEVEL];
    const int l=LEVEL;
#endif

    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
        max[i]=INT_MIN;

    for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<l;j++) {
            if (a[i]>max[j]) {
                for(k=l-1;k>j;k--) {
                    max[k]=max[k-1];
                }
                max[j]=a[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    i=max[l-1];
#if LEVEL == 0
    free(max);
#endif

    return i;
}

int main()
{
    int n,a[1000],i;

#if RAND_VALUE != 0
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
#endif

    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
#if RAND_VALUE != 0
        /* Computes numbers between +100 and -100 */
        a[i]=rand() % 200 - 100;
        printf("%+4d ",a[i]);
#else
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
#endif
    }

#if RAND_VALUE != 0
    puts("");
#endif

    printf("The 3rd largest is: %d\n",
#if LEVEL == 0
           levelLargest(a,n,3)
#else
           levelLargest(a,n)
#endif
    );

    return 0;
}
```

P.S.: May be that for big level (level x) values might be better to sort the values using qsort sorting the values in descending order and then to indicate the xth element of the sorted array.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** Using Hashing

```
private static void ThirdLargestElement()
{
    int[] arr = { 2, 4, 1, 3, 5 };
    int third = GetThirdLargestElement(arr);
    Console.WriteLine("Third element :{0}", third);
}

private static int GetThirdLargestElement(int[] arr)
{
    HashSet<int> track = new HashSet<int>();
    int size = arr.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        track.Add(arr[i]);
        if (track.Count >= 3)
            track.Remove(track.Min());
    }

    if (track.Count == 3)
        return track.Min();

    return track.Min();
}
```